drbl on Ubuntu 24.04 missing mkpxeinitrd-net
I'm trying to configure drbl in Ubuntu Server 24.04.
I've installed it simply by using the command
sudo apt-get install drbl

But when I try to configure it with sudo drblsrv -i when it asks me to update the operating system, I select yes, and the following erro message appears:
E: Unable to locate package mkpxeinitrd-net
Warning! Some necessary packages are not installed! If you continue, maybe something will go wrong! It is better to exit now and check your /etc/apt/sources.list and internet link!
Press Ctrl-C to stop the program! Or Press "Enter" to continue... 

The problem is that I cannot found mkpxeinitrd-net. I've also search for some info about the repository but I did not find anything.
How can I install correctly this package so I can continue configuring drbl?
